# Fazer uma matriz de origens e destinos

Tags: r, matriz

Preciso preencher uma tabela com origens e destinos de forma que cada célula contenha o total de pessoas que saem de uma localidade para outra.

O banco de dados possui um id para cada observação, além da origem e do destino. Cada observação possui um "peso" que corresponde a uma quantidade de pessoas para aquela observação. Segue um exemplo:

```r
# Banco de dados de exemplo:
localidades <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                          Peso_id = c(5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 7),
                          Origem = factor(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"),
                                      levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
                          Destino = factor(c("C", "D", "A", "C", "A", "D"),
                                       levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
                         )

localidades
#>   id Peso_id Origem Destino
#> 1  1       5      A       C
#> 2  2       5      A       D
#> 3  3      10      B       A
#> 4  4      10      B       C
#> 5  5      10      B       A
#> 6  6       7      C       D
```

## Matriz de origens e destinos?

Se eu usar a função `table()` como faço abaixo, será contabilizado apenas o nº de observações (`id`) em vez do número de pessoas (ex: somar `Peso_id`) para cada par de localidades:

```r
minha_tabela <- table(localidades$Origem , localidades$Destino)

minha_tabela
#>    
#>     A B C D
#>   A 0 0 1 1
#>   B 2 0 1 0
#>   C 0 0 0 1
#>   D 0 0 0 0
```

No entanto eu preciso que seja considerado na conta o `Peso_id` na hora de montar a tabela. No final eu quero obter essas informações:

```r
minha_tabela_OD
#>    
#>     A   B  C  D
#>   A 0   0  5  5
#>   B 20  0  10 0
#>   C 0   0  0  7
#>   D 0   0  0  0
```

Como faz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `xtabs()`:

```
minha_tabela_OD <- xtabs(localidades$Peso_id ~ localidades$Origem + localidades$Destino)

minha_tabela_OD
#>               localidades$Destino
#> localidades$Origem  A  B  C  D
#>                  A  0  0  5  5
#>                  B 20  0 10  0
#>                  C  0  0  0  7
#>                  D  0  0  0  0
```